# How to use python collections for custom classes

Tags: python, data-structures, collections, abstract-data-type, functools

Still somewhat perplexed by python and it's magic functional programming, so I tend to find myself writing code that is more towards the Java paradigm of programming as opposed to Idiomatic Python.

My question is somewhat related to: [How do I make a custom class a collection in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528933/how-do-i-make-a-custom-class-a-collection-in-python)

The only difference is I have nested objects (using composition). The **VirtualPage** object is comprised of a list of **PhysicalPage** objects. I have a function which can take a list of **PhyscialPage** objects and coalesce all of the details into a single named tuple I call **PageBoundary**. Essentially it's a serialization function which can spit out a tuple comprised of an integer range which represents the physical page and the line number in the page. From this I can easily sort and order VirtualPages among one another (that's the idea at least):

```
PageBoundary = collections.namedtuple('PageBoundary', 'begin end')
```

I also have a function which can take a **PageBoundary** namedtuple and de-serialize or expand the tuple into a list of **PhysicalPages**. It's preferable that these two data storage classes not change as it will break any downstream code.

Here is a snippet of my custom python2.7 class. It is composed of lot things one is list which contains a the object **PhysicalPage**:

```
class VirtualPage(object):
    def __init__(self, _physical_pages=list()):
        self.physcial_pages = _physcial_pages


class PhysicalPage(object):
    # class variables: number of digits each attribute gets
    _PAGE_PAD, _LINE_PAD = 10, 12 

    def __init__(self, _page_num=-1):
        self.page_num = _page_num
        self.begin_line_num = -1
        self.end_line_num = -1

    def get_cannonical_begin(self):
        return int(''.join([str(self.page_num).zfill(PhysicalPage._PAGE_PAD),
                    str(tmp_line_num).zfill(PhysicalPage._LINE_PAD) ]))

    def get_cannonical_end(self):
        pass # see get_cannonical_begin() implementation

    def get_canonical_page_boundaries(self):
        return PageBoundary(self.get_canonical_begin(), self.get_canonical_end())
```

I would like to leverage some templated collection (from the python collections module) to easily sort and compare as list or set of **VirtualPage** classes. Also would like some advice on the layout of my data storage classes: **VirtualPage** and **PhysicalPage**.

Given either a sequence of **VirtualPages** or as in the example below:

```
vp_1 = VirtualPage(list_of_physical_pages)
vp_1_copy = VirtualPage(list_of_physical_pages)
vp_2 = VirtualPage(list_of_other_physical_pages)
```

I want to easily answer questions like this:

```
>>> vp_2 in vp_1 
False
>>> vp_2 < vp_1
True
>>> vp_1 == vp_1_copy
True
```

Right off the bat it seems obvious that the **VirtualPage** class needs to call get_cannonical_page_boundaries or even implement the function itself. At a minimum it should loop over it's **PhysicalPage** list to implement the required functions (**lt**() and **eq**()) so I can compare b/w **VirtualPages**.

1.) Currently I'm struggling with implementing some of the comparison functions. One big obstacle is how to compare a tuple? Do I create my own **lt**() function by creating a custom class which extends some type of collection:

```
import collections as col
import functools

@total_ordering
class AbstractVirtualPageContainer(col.MutableSet):

    def __lt__(self, other):
        '''What type would other be?
        Make comparison by first normalizing to a comparable type: PageBoundary
        '''
        pass
```

2.) Should the comparison function implementation exist in the **VirtualPage** class instead?

I was leaning towards some type of Set data structure as the properties of the data I'm modeling has the concept of uniqueness: i.e. physical page values cannot overlap and to some extend act as a linked list. Also would setter or getter functions, implemented via @ decorator functions be of any use here?

Comment: What does it mean to say `vp_2 in vp_1`? That they have at least one physical page in common, or all pages in vp_2 are also in vp_1?  Similarly for `<`, `==`, etc.  Are these operations defined in terms of physical pages or PageBoundaries?  I think `get_cannonical_begin()` can be simplified to `return self.page_num*10**PhysicalPage._LINE_PAD + tmp_line_num`

Comment: Sorry keep pressing enter hehe
Say I start with an initial set of PhysicalPages in a volume: **pp_init_set**. My goal is to break **pp_init_set** into distinct **VirtualPage** objects by defining their page+line breaks in the form of **PhysicalPages**. 

When I'm done I should have set/list of unique **VirtualPage** objects. When I sum this set up I should get the original **pp_init_set**. This implies there are neither missing pages (holes) nor overlapping pages.
Also this identity holds:
    VirtualPage[i].physical_pages[-1].end_line_num ==  VirtualPage[i+ 1].physical_pages[0].begin_line_num

Comment: Maybe vp_2 in vp_1 isn't that useful. I really would like to define enough of the function in https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections-abstract-base-classes
to have my own MutableSet of **VirtualPages** which I can then, at a high level, do vp_2 - vp_1 to get the difference b/w two touching **VirtualPages**. In this case I would expect to implicity get a new **VirtualPage** where the two rules I stated above are still valid. **PageBoundaries** is just a simple translation function to represent a list of **PhysicalPages**. Thanks for the response btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like the code below.  Not tested; certainly not tested for your application or with your data, YMMV, etc.

```
from collections import namedtuple

# PageBoundary is a subclass of named tuple with special relational
# operators. __le__ and __ge__ are left undefined because they don't
# make sense for this class.
class PageBoundary(namedtuple('PageBoundary', 'begin end')):
    # to prevent making an instance dict (See namedtuple docs)
    __slots__ = ()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.end < other.begin

    def __eq__(self, other):
        # you can put in an assertion if you are concerned the
        # method might be called with the wrong type object
        assert isinstance(other, PageBoundary), "Wrong type for other"

        return self.begin == other.begin and self.end == other.end

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return other < self


class PhysicalPage(object):
    # class variables: number of digits each attribute gets
    _PAGE_PAD, _LINE_PAD = 10, 12 

    def __init__(self, page_num):
        self.page_num = page_num

        # single leading underscore is 'private' by convention
        # not enforced by the language
        self._begin = self.page_num * 10**PhysicalPage._LINE_PAD + tmp_line_num
        #self._end = ...however you calculate this...                    ^ not defined yet

        self.begin_line_num = -1
        self.end_line_num = -1

    # this serves the purpose of a `getter`, but looks just like
    # a normal class member access. used like x = page.begin  
    @property
    def begin(self):
        return self._begin

    @property
    def end(self):
        return self._end

    def __lt__(self, other):
        assert(isinstance(other, PhysicalPage))
        return self._end < other._begin

    def __eq__(self, other):
        assert(isinstance(other, PhysicalPage))
        return self._begin, self._end == other._begin, other._end

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return other < self


class VirtualPage(object):
    def __init__(self, physical_pages=None):
        self.physcial_pages = sorted(physcial_pages) if physical_pages else []

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.physical_pages and other.physical_pages:
            return self.physical_pages[-1].end < other.physical_pages[0].begin

        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.physical_pages and other.physical_pages:
            return self.physical_pages == other.physical_pages

        else:
            raise ValueError

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return other < self
```

And a few observations:

Although there is no such thing as "private" members in Python classes, it is a convention to begin a variable name with a single underscore, `_`, to indicate it is not part of the public interface of the class / module/ etc.  So, naming method parameters of public methods with an '_', doesn't seem correct, e.g., `def __init__(self, _page_num=-1)`.

Python generally doesn't use setters / getters; just use the attributes directly.  If attribute values need to be calculated, or other some other processing is needed use the `@property` decorator (as shown for PhysicalPage.begin() above).

It's generally not a good idea to initialize a default function argument with a mutable object.  `def __init__(self, physical_pages=list())` does not initialize physical_pages with a new empty list each time; rather, it uses the same list every time.  If the list is modified, at the next function call physical_pages will be initialized with the modified list.  See VirtualPages initializer for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! I can definitely use a lot of these ideas. And also thanks for the default argument and mutable objects. Sounds like a really good way to shoot yourself in the foot and not know it. Appreciate your time!